# How to cut everything after string Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've got some strings like:

```
Cola12018 

ColaKKK112018

Cola-22018
```

And I need retrieve just Cola from them and delete everything after in order to use further.

I tried

$cola = 'Cola.*'

What did I miss?

The main thing - I want to check that the word begins with "Cola"

Comment: `$strings -replace $cola,'Cola'`

Comment: `$strings -replace '(Cola).*', '$1'`

Comment: To also anchor the match at the start of each input string: `$strings -replace '^(Cola).*', '$1'` Note that non-matching strings are passed through.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
$string="Cola12018 

ColaKKK112018

Cola-22018" 
[regex]::Matches($string, '(?m)^Cola').Value
```

Explanation:

(?m) = multiline match

^ = starts with

Answer (score 0):

Or just specify what part of the string you'd like to use if it's positional...

```
$string = 'Cola12018','ColaKKK112018','Cola-22018'
$string | foreach {-join $_[0..3]}
```